# How to get Xbox avatar in your windows 8.1 store app ?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, avatar

In my app, I want to access and use user's Xbox avatar. I came to know that Xbox Live Avatar API is not exposed to projects! Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the 3D model or a picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get gamertag from live id API, you can use [this](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/avatars/) :

Small http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/sample/avatarpic-s.png

[image]

Large http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/sample/avatarpic-l.png

[image]

Full body http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/sample/avatar-body.png

[image]

Of course, you have to replace "sample" with a gamertag.

Comment: it works fine if user is online. is there any way to get avatar even user is offline ? @aloisdg

Comment: This works fine. You can make a GET request with `https://xboxapi.com/v1/profile/[gamertag]` To know if the user is offline or online. (more custom api [here](https://xboxapi.com/) and [here](https://xboxliveapi.com/docs)

Comment: thank you!this is really helpful. One last thing, can i get my own Xbox animated avatar from my local machine using win8.??? [while ofline] @aloisdg

Comment: I dont know if you can. You can search in the API.

Comment: Ah, how great would be, if it would be possible to get 3d model of avatar.